# How can I create the .zip file for a C# Azure Functions zip deployment in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: azure-functions

Using Visual Studio 2019, I created a C#, .NET Core Azure Function.

I like to do a zip deployment the way that it is explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

What is the most automated option to use Visual Studio 2019 to create the zip file for the zip deployment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Navigate to the root folder of your Functionapp where your `functionApp.csproj` exists and run the below command

```
dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=Package;CreatePackageOnPublish=true
```

This will publish the folders and files which are ready to be zipped in the `bin/Publish` folder. You can now use the `Compress-Archive` powershell cmdlet to zip the folder or any other way which you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for help. Should I rename the Publish folder to any specific name, or should I just zip the folder "Publish" ?

Comment: @AllanXu you can rename it whatever you like :xD. Also please reward me a green check mark

Comment: Sure thing. One last question, is there any article or doc that I can read more about the command line you posted? How did you find about all the parameters?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/building-and-packaging-web-application-projects

Comment: Thanks, but all the -p: oprions remains your secret souce and mystery ;)

Comment: You can as well use `dotnet publish -o OutputDirectory` command. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21)